# How to get TypeLiteral binding or can say instance from injector [Google Guice]

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, guice-servlet

I have `Dao<T>` interface which is implemented by `BaseDao<T>` class & `BaseDao<T>` later extended by many of subclass like `UserDao` class.

```
interface Dao<T>{}

abstract class BaseDao<T> implements Dao<T>{}

class UserDao extends BaseDao<User>{}
```

Following is the guice binding

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<Dao<User>>() {
        }).annotatedWith(Names.named("UserDao")).toProvider(UserDaoProvider.class);
```

Provider looks like..

```
public class UserDaoProvider implements Provider<UserDao> {

    @Override
    public UserDao get() {
        return new UserDao();
    }

}
```

Now i am trying to get it from guice injector

```
injector.getInstance(Key.get(new TypeLiteral<Dao<User>>() {
                }, Names.named("UserDao")));
```

But i am getting `null`

Please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you properly register your module? `Guice.createInjector(new ServletModule(), new YourDaoModule())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get instance of UserDao as follows

```
injector.getInstance(UserDao.class);
```